# Not able to test my async code in node.js using mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have the following code:

```
function ToDo(){
    //something
}

ToDo.prototype.doAsync = function(cb){
    setTimeout(cb,2000,true);
};
```

Now I'm trying to test this code using mocha:

```
//async
describe('doAsync', function(){

     it('getting callback in two seconds', function(done){
        todo.doAsync(function(){
            done();
        });

     });
});
```

as the result my testing fails.

```
 1 failing

  1) todo doAsync getting callback in two seconds:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
      at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:139:19)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test most likely takes a tiny bit more than the default 2000ms timeout to complete. So you need to increase it. In your situation, since you will most likely *always* need to increase it whenever you run your tests for `doAsync`, I'd call the `timeout` method of the top level `describe`:

```
describe('doAsync', function () {
    this.timeout(3000);

    // tests...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the timeout for the mocha tests, by using the `-t` flag:

> -t, --timeout               set test-case timeout in milliseconds [2000]

So for instance:

> mocha -t 5000

The default time is 2 seconds, and it looks like that timeout is being hit before the tests complete, so Mocha is assuming there was a problem and halting the tests.